# Hive Context to load into a table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am selecting a entire table and loading into a new table.It is loaded correctly but the value is appending not overwriting.
Spark version 1.6
Below is the code snippet

```
DataFrame df = hiveContext.createDataFrame(JavaRDD<Row>, StructType);
df.registerTempTable("tempregtable"); 
String query="insert into employee select * from tempregtable";
hiveContext.sql(query);
```

I am droping and creating the table (employee) and executing the above code.But still the old row value gets appended with new row.For eg if I am inserted four rows and dropped the table and again inserting four rows totally 8 rows got added.Kindly help me, how to overwrite the data instead of appending.

Regards
Prakash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
String query="insert overwrite table employee select * from tempregtable";
```

`INSERT OVERWRITE` will overwrite any existing data in the table or partition

`INSERT INTO` will append to the table or partition

Reference: [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)